# Capture whole XML tag containing search pattern

Tags: xml, bash, grep, text-processing

I need to capture an XML tag containing a specific pattern in order to copy it into another file. Complication is that the tag repeats multiple times and the number of lines inside varies.

Input:

```
<MainTag>
    <Tag1>text</Tag1>
    <Tag2>text</Tag2>
   <Info>SearchPattern</Info>
    <Tag3>text</Tag3>
    .....
</MainTag>
<MainTag>
    <Tag1>text</Tag1>
    <Tag2>text</Tag2>
   <Info>SearchPattern</Info>
    <Tag3>text</Tag3>
    .....
</MainTag>
<MainTag>
..........
</MainTag>
```

Output:

```
<MainTag>
    <Tag1>text</Tag1>
    <Tag2>text</Tag2>
   <Info>SearchPattern</Info>
    <Tag3>text</Tag3>
    .....
</MainTag>
```

Using `pcregrep` isn't an option.

I tried to use `grep -Pzo '(?s)<MainTag.+?Searchpattern.+?</MainTag>'` but it captures text from the very first occurence of the Main tag.

Comment: please use xml aware tools like xmlstarlet or languages like perl, python, etc with xml library... if you have no choice but to use available cli tools, this may help but will likely break for some cases - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335497/get-text-between-start-pattern-and-end-pattern-based-on-pattern-between-start-an

Comment: I can't use anything except cli but this seems to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just like *Sundeep* commented, please use xml aware tools to process xml, like [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html).

> Xidel is a command line tool to download and extract data from HTML/XML pages as well as JSON-APIs, using CSS, XPath 3.0, XQuery 3.0, JSONiq or pattern templates. It can also create new or transformed XML/HTML/JSON documents.

```
xidel -s input.xml -e '//MainTag ! file:write(concat("output",position(),".xml"),outer-xml())'
```

For every "MainTag"-node a [file will be created](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#file-write) (`output1.xml` and `output2.xml` in this case) with the [outer-xml](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-outer-xml).

Also see [this xidelcgi demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3CMainTag%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTag1%3Etext%3C%2FTag1%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTag2%3Etext%3C%2FTag2%3E%0A%20%20%20%3CInfo%3ESearchPattern%3C%2FInfo%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTag3%3Etext%3C%2FTag3%3E%0A%3C%2FMainTag%3E%0A%3CMainTag%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTag4%3Etext%3C%2FTag4%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTag5%3Etext%3C%2FTag5%3E%0A%20%20%20%3CInfo%3ESearchPattern%3C%2FInfo%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTag6%3Etext%3C%2FTag6%3E%0A%3C%2FMainTag%3E&=&extract=%2F%2FMainTag%20!%20(concat(%22output%22%2Cposition()%2C%22.xml%22)%2Couter-xml()%2C%22%22)&=%2C%22%22&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto).